# Looping through checkboxes and choosing the :checked checkbox value?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have an array for each array attribute an input checkbox is looped, I can return the value of the checked input, but it outputs every instance of the array.

```
     $('#moon-generator-settings .moon-generator-attr').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() !== '') {
            $('#moon-generator-result').val( $('#moon-generator-result').val() + ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + '="' + $(this).val() + '"' );                
        }
```

this outputs code into the editor on wordpress the code should look like this

```
      [icons myicon="globe"]
```

but instead returns

```
      [icons myicon="globe" myicon="pencil" myicon="plus" myicon="minus" myicon="left" myicon="up" myicon="right" myicon="down" myicon="home" myicon="pause" myicon="fast-fw" myicon="fast-bw" myicon="to-end" myicon="to-start" myicon="stop"]
```

where myicon is, that is where  $(this).attr('name') is, and $(this).val() is obviously the value myicon equals, the value inside my input. I am having trouble only returning the checked value of the input, not all of them, which causes me to suspect the checkboxes are not returning properly.

here is some more code.

```
     $('#moon-generator-insert').live('click', function(event) {

    var queried_shortcode = $('#moon-generator-select').find(':checked').val();
    var moon_compatibility_mode_prefix = $('#moon-compatibility-mode-prefix').val();

    $('#moon-generator-result').val('[' + moon_compatibility_mode_prefix + queried_shortcode);

    $('#moon-generator-settings .moon-generator-attr').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() !== '') {
            $('#moon-generator-result').val( $('#moon-generator-result').val() + ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + '="' + $(this).val() + '"' );                
        }

    });

    $('#moon-generator-result').val($('#moon-generator-result').val() + ']');
```

Ive read as much as I could and I dont think the .find(:checked).val() should be written that way?

Here is the parsed php in HTML format

```
     <div class="icons">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="globe" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="pencil" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="plus" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="minus" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="left" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="up" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="right" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="down" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="home" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="pause" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="fast-fw" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="fast-bw" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="to-end" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="to-start" name="myicon">
     <input class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="stop" name="myicon">
     </div>
```

So here is what does work... when using a select options dropdown there isnt a problem...

```
      <select id="moon-generator-attr-style" class="moon-generator-attr" name="style">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
```

the Jquery

```
      $('#moon-generator-insert').live('click', function(event) {
    var queried_shortcode = $('#moon-generator-select').find(':selected').val();
    var moon_compatibility_mode_prefix = $('#moon-compatibility-mode-prefix').val();
    $('#moon-generator-result').val('[' + moon_compatibility_mode_prefix + queried_shortcode);
    $('#moon-generator-settings .moon-generator-attr').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() !== '' ) {
            $('#moon-generator-result').val( $('#moon-generator-result').val() + ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + '="' + $(this).val() + '"' );
        }
    });
    $('#moon-generator-result').val($('#moon-generator-result').val() + ']');
```

thanks everyone, this is MUCH APPRECIATED here is updated code...

```
      $('#moon-generator-insert').live('click', function(event) {
    var queried_shortcode = $('#moon-generator-select').find(':selected').val();

    var moon_compatibility_mode_prefix = $('#moon-compatibility-mode-prefix').val();
    var result = $(".moon-generator-attr:checked").map(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.attr("name") + '="' + $this.val() + '"';
    }).get().join(" ");

    $('#moon-generator-result').val('[' + moon_compatibility_mode_prefix + queried_shortcode);
    $('#moon-generator-settings .moon-generator-attr').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() !== '' ) {
            $('#moon-generator-result').val( $('#moon-generator-result').val() + ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + '="' + result + '"' );
        }
    });
    $('#moon-generator-result').val($('#moon-generator-result').val() + ']');
```

outputs to this

```
      [icons myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop"" myicon="myicon="stop""]
```

here is the checkbox php

```
      // Checkbox
        if ( count( $attr_info['checks'] ) && $attr_info['checks'] ) {              
            $return .= '<div class="icons">';
            foreach ( $attr_info['checks'] as $attr_value ) {
                $attr_value_selected = ( $attr_info['default'] == $attr_value ) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';        
            $return .= '<input name="' . $attr_name . '" class="moon-generator-attr" type="checkbox" value="' . $attr_value . '" '.$attr_value_selected.'>  </input> ';

            }
            $return .= '</div>';
        }
```

here is the array

```
      'icons' => array(
            'name' => 'Icons',
            'type' => 'single',
            'atts' => array(
                'myicon' => array(
                    'checks' => array(
                        'globe',
                        'pencil',
                        'plus',
                        'minus',
                        'left',
                        'up',
                        'right',
                        'down',
                        'home',
                        'pause',
                        'fast-fw',
                        'fast-bw',
                        'to-end',
                        'to-start',
                        'stop',
                    ),
                    'desc' => __( 'Add an icon', 'moon-shortcodes' )
                )
            ),
            'usage' => '[icons myicon="globe"][/icons]',
            'desc' => __( 'Add Icon', 'moon-shortcodes' )
        ),
```

Comment: can you share the html?  at least more of it so we can see what you are iterating?

Comment: Use the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: Ever thought about caching your selectors? Makes life easy. And (ok, depending on the jQ version you use) but **.live()** is long time **deprecated!**

Comment: :selected does not work on checkboxes or radio buttons, use :checked instead.

Comment: This is an open source plugin I am using as a base framework, I know that by default there was :selected because it had options inside a dropdown select.. Im basically adding a checkbox loop... but I thought I got rid of :selected, where do you see :selected in the code up there?

Comment: Oh wow, that was a mistake, been overloading my brain lol... but inside the code I am using :checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, whether or not the checkboxes are checked, they still have a value, so `.val()` will return the value even if unchecked.  You need to filter the checkboxes by the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) when looping over them.

Here is code which will return a string containing all of the checked items:

```
var result = $(".moon-generator-attr:checked").map(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        return $this.attr("name") + '="' + $this.val() + '"';
    }).get().join(" ");

alert("Result='" + result + "'");
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bman654/NE8M9/
Just click some checkboxes and click `Go`

-- Updated code from OP --

```
var queried_shortcode = $('#moon-generator-select').find(':selected').val();

var moon_compatibility_mode_prefix = $('#moon-compatibility-mode-prefix').val();
var checkedString = $(".moon-generator-attr:checked").map(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.attr("name") + '="' + $this.val() + '"';
}).get().join(" ");

var resultString = '[' + moon_compatibility_mode_prefix +
                   queried_shortcode + ' ' + checkedString + ']';

$('#moon-generator-result').val(resultString);
```

Comment: Ok PERFECT, this is what I had a feeling I kept looking things up along these terms, wouldn't toggle also be another word appropriate? Anyways, im not 100% sure how to blend that in with my existing code.. I bet its quite remedial, I am just out of brain power haha, could you explain how to incorperate it? Would be SOO great of you!

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: do I write that variable and place result where the val should be?

Comment: that sounds about right.. but with hours of fiddling id like to just know what the proper way is before fiddling again

Comment: something like `$('#moon-generator-result').val($('#moon-generator-result').val() + result + ']');`

Comment: Yeah, what I thought.. ok saaweeet definitely gonna give you your props... very clean solution IMO.. thanks again..

Comment: And cache your lookups.  Instead of typing `$('#moon-generator-result')` over and over, just do `var $result = $('#moon-generator-result')` and use `$result.val()` everywhere.  Much less typing and much faster (jQuery has to search your document everytime you type it out the long way).

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, hate to have to ask this but solution worked great except I get [icons myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe"" myicon="myicon="globe""]

Comment: ... not to mention it makes things **WAY** more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Doh I feel like a really bad developer, but this is how ya learn, from the good guys

Comment: @jahroy - $(...).map() returns a new jQuery object (which is just an array really).  [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) will get you the underlying array from the jQuery object.  It is a little quirky and I prefer using ES5 [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (`$elements.get().map(function (element) { ... }).join(" ")`) over `$.map` but since I don't know what the OP is targeting I stuck with `$.map`

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry I updated my answer with your code.  You do not need the `each` loop anymore.  The `map()` code is looping through the checked items and constructing your string.

Comment: YOU'RE BRILLIANT MAN!! This stuff can get tricky.. I just need to practice, practice, practice, a days work was solved in minuets for you, hope to be on that level one day.. Kudos my man!!

Comment: It was probably an easy solution to you, but it allows me to progress with my development, and that means more that you can imagine... I vowed to get a solution before going to bed.. and Im TIRED.. thanks again

Comment: @Brandon - Thanks.  I realized it was a jQuery function and read the docs.  I've seen map() a ton, but I hadn't seen _$(...).get()_ before.  Stoked to learn a new trick.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this too complicated.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vULZw/3/) that shows a working example.

I simplified your code to this:

```
$('#butt').click(function () {
    var txt = $('#output').text();
    $('.moon-generator-attr').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.prop('checked')) {
            var name = $this.attr('name');
            var val = $this.val();
            txt += ' ' + name + '="' + val + '"';
        }
    });
    $('#output').text(txt);
});
```